# Wine shows 0 Disk Space

Tags: wine

I am using wine to install Matlab but wine is showing that there is no disk space in your drive. But i have still more that 50 GB free space in my drive. I used matlab 2011 setup also to install but problem is remaining same.

Here is status of my machine

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       47929224 20667520  24820336  46% /

udev             1019496        4   1019492   1% /dev

tmpfs             411056      840    410216   1% /run

none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock

none             1027640      156   1027484   1% /run/shm

/dev/sda5        1888268    29460   1761224   2% /boot

/dev/sdb1        7822424  7711664    110760  99% /media/06D8A9D6D8A9C3F1

/dev/loop0       5073422  5073422         0 100% /media/matlab
```

Comment: please open your terminal and type `df -l` and add the result to your question.

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Here is status of my machine

Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       47929224 20667520  24820336  46% /
udev             1019496        4   1019492   1% /dev
tmpfs             411056      840    410216   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1027640      156   1027484   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5        1888268    29460   1761224   2% /boot
/dev/sdb1        7822424  7711664    110760  99% /media/06D8A9D6D8A9C3F1
/dev/loop0       5073422  5073422         0 100% /media/matlab

Comment: just take a look at last line, you see that you've mounted the matlab from a device . So it's better to copy it on your HD and then try it with Wine .

Comment: @OnlyMAJ i am already tried but nothing happen. Problem remain same.
And i think there is no effect on installation whether it is from media or a folder on HD

Comment: can u explain what instructions you have done exactly ?

Comment: I copied whole directory to a folder on my desktop and try to execute command #./setup
And Matlab installer GUI windows appeared and than i follow the basic steps which require for the installation of a  software in windows. I provide key reached at the panel where we can select the directory to install the software.
But it shows 0 space in program files but wine cmd.exe shows that there is 33 GB free space in c drive.
i tried to change the drive and mount it into the wine as a windows directory but doesn't work.

Comment: and what was the result ??

Comment: GUI mode shows 0 disk space